# Why can't I see my remote git repositery?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Here is what I did:

1. Created a Ruby on Rails app.
2. Initialized empty git rep
3. Made changes to my app and saved them (git add -A and git commit -m "blahblah")
4. Deployed to Heroku.

But when I visit git hub it shows zero repos?

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Your steps don't include a "push to GitHub" operation...

Answer (score 3):

I think you confound github and heroku.
It's two differents repository.

Deploying to heroku with something like this:

```
git push heroku master
```

does not affect your github account.

You can have several repository for the same project.
To add a repository:

```
git remote add NAME_OF_YOUR_REPO URL_OF_YOUR_REPO
```

(you can create a project in github, and they will git you a URL_OF_YOUR_REPO)
example:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/user/repo.git
```

after you can do:

```
git push origin master
```

and you will see your commits on github.